# Is it possible to recycle the glass bottles and jar in desired shape and size by melting?

Tags: material-selection, glass

I have a lot of glass bottles and jars. I want to convert them into new items of different styles and shapes. Can a glass object be molded into a new shape by melting? If yes, then how?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, The general term is 'bottle slumping'.  There are several [images on pinterest](https://www.pinterest.com/annacarle/slumped-glass-bottles/).  The glass is heated to the point that it can be shaped.  Current trends are to use a Kiln, with temperatures between 500F and 1500F

I have memories from local carnivals in the 1960s and 1970 of the bottles being heated in a liquid, shaped and given as prizes or sold. I had a coke bottle for several years that was obtained from the carnival.

Comment: Is bottle slumping possible without a kiln?

Comment: @ChrisRogers see Related [Is it possible to melt a glass bottle without a kiln?](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/q/3337/6431)

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't recommend it. Glass especially bottles/jars can explode when heated like that sending pieces of hot glass flying in all directions  I recommend getting a good art and craft  kit specifically for glass.